# gksudo 2 commands with one PW entry?

Tags: nautilus, gedit, gksu

Before upgrading to 12.04 (from 10.04) I used this little launcher script:

```
 #!/bin/bash  
 gksudo nautilus /var/www/DFDII & sleep 5; gksudo gedit /var/www/DFDII/iindex.php
```

This script opened both nautilus and gedit with just one PW entry, now it asks for PW twice ?

Also, annoyingly, now gedit also open "untitled document 1" (close > save changes ? NOOOOO!...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main options:

1. Demand that the whole script be run as root. Lots of scripts just exit out and suggest the user prepend the command with `gksu`.
2. Run things like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   gksu -- bash -c 'whoami; whoami; whoami # all these return root'
   ```

Comment: Thank you Oli - this works:     
**gksu -- bash -c 'nautilus & sleep 5; gedit'**
But only if I add the "sleep 5" - without it, gedit doesn't start until I close nautilus - why ?

Comment: @Thomas because nautilus is running in the foreground. It's not running as that user so takes over the terminal. The `&` puts it in the background. `nautilus & gedit` should work.

Comment: Right you are :) Thanks again. Any idea why gedit (also) opens "untitled document 1" (or why it thinks it's been altered when I try to close it) ?

Comment: Sorry - it's a known bug but that's all I can say to help. I tried playing around with its options but nothing seems to work around the tab issue. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/890041